# A multi-sized image gallery grid

Tags: image, thumbnails, image-galleries

One thing I've noticed when working with Expression Engine, is that when image galleries are created, with images being loaded dynamically from a channel, the images tend to be the same size dimension and so the end result is an equal grid.

[image: Equal thumbnail grid example]

There's absolutely nothing wrong with this, but having used this method/layout for so long site after site, I thought I would venture out a bit and see if anyone out there with a bit more know-how could explain **1.** If it's possible and **2.** how I could go about creating a dynamic gallery with a similar layout to the following example;

[image: Multi-sized thumbnail example]

I'm unsure how possible it would be to replicate this effect from say, an Assets field full of multiple images. I suppose multiple images being pulled through this way would have a uniformed formatting, such as height and width etc, therefore creating an equal grid layout

I'm aware of plugins such as [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which achieve this kind of desired effect. But are those sorts of plugins the only way around?, besides hard coding the images with set widths and heights (which could impact a responsive site).

My gut tells me that it would be tricky to pull through multiple images dynamically from a channel and arrange them in this way. But hey, maybe I'm missing something obvious. That's why I'm asking I guess.

Any advice, as always, is much appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about front-end development, not ExpressionEngine.

Comment: @kgrote Apologies, but I tried to focus the question around getting this kind of layout of different sized images using data from a channel field.

Comment: You can configure image manipulations in any size you want for file upload directories. The placement of the images though is unrelated to EE.

Answer (score 3):

I've had great experience with masonry very simple to implement and is responsive as well.

If you are wanting categorized photos i would set up a single channel for each image. That way you could categorize the images and display different ones depending on the filter that is activated on the site. I wouldn't put a set hight and width to the images with css set the img property to width:100%; and it will fit the to the parent element horizontally. Then with masonry it will fit the parent elements into a mortar style layout like you have above.

I have done a few times and it works great not only with photo galleries but blogs as well.

Comment: This is good. I'd add that using Channel Images from DevDemon can help organize and categorize your images from different channel entries.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback guys. I'm aware of both your suggestions. I will look further into both and see if I can make progress. Cheers